# Custom login and registration with auth laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create the first project with *Laravel 5.7*.

In this project I have three different areas with three different login (ex. Login for users, login for admin, login for technicians).

Now, I would like to customize the first login (url, html, input, class, db table, db column ecc...) but I don't know how to do.

The **URL** of first login is `website.com/public/users`

My **Table** is:

```
CREATE TABLE `gf_users` (
  `gf_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gf_name` text NOT NULL,
  `gf_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `gf_password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
)
```

I have searched a lot and with the information that I have found, I have tried to do this:

**config/auth.php**:

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\GFUsers::class
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('users', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginFormUsers')->name('login');
Route::post('users', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function showLoginFormUsers(){
   return view('users.login');
}

public function username(){
   return 'gf_email';
}
```

**GFUsers.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class GFUsers extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'gf_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'gf_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'gf_email', 'gf_password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'gf_password'
    ];


    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->gf_password;
    }
}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ asset('/users') }}">
@csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="gf_email" id="gf_email" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="gf_password" id="gf_password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

If I compile the form and click on login button, this refresh the page but I don't understand if it works or not.

**1**. Is the procedure correct?
**2**. Are there some errors? 
**3**. Have I forget something?
**4**. What can I do for registration?

Comment: config/auth.php missing custom guard for gf_user.Registration is simple but authentication will take you some time

Comment: One question per question

Comment: Maybe this would be better on Code review

Comment: The best way to create a single table for user and manage an another table for role and another table for their mapping and create a single user that will check the user role and redirect user accordingly

Comment: @MayankPandeyz but my problem is how to do a custom login in laravel.

Comment: @LimKeanPhang can you help me to create custom guard for gf_user? or at least understand how I can do it.

Comment: 'gfusers' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'gfusers',
        ], 
@Giu , Just copy the default one and make some modification

Comment: @LimKeanPhang ok, I have added the guard, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research I have find my solution. I hope that this can help someone else.
I have customized: id, username, password and remember token in the table and the files User.php, LoginController.php.

==Table==:

```
CREATE TABLE `gf_users` (
  `gf_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gf_name` text NOT NULL,
  `gf_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `gf_password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `gf_remember_token` varchar(300) NOT NULL
)
```

**web.php**:

```
// Authentication Routes
Route::get('users', 'Auth\NewLoginController@showLoginFormUsers')->name('login');
Route::post('users', 'Auth\NewLoginController@checklogin');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\NewLoginController@logout')->name('logout');
// Registration Routes
Route::get('users/registration', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationFormUsers')->name('register');
Route::post('users/registration', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

**NewLoginController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/users/details';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    
    
    public function showLoginFormUsers(){
        return view('users.login');
    }
    
    public function username(){
        return 'gf_email';
    }
    
    function checklogin(Request $request){
        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'input-email' => 'required', 
            'input-password' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $user_data = array(
            'gf_email'  => $request->get('input-email'),
            'password' => $request->get('input-password')
        );
        
        if(!Auth::attempt($user_data)){
            return redirect('users');
        }
        
        if ( Auth::check() ) {
            return redirect('users/details');
        }
    }
    
    function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('users');
    }

}
```

**NewUser.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'gf_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'gf_id';
    public $timestamps = false; 
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'gf_email', 'gf_password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'gf_password', 'gf_remember_token',
    ];
    
    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->gf_password;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->gf_remember_token;
    }
    
    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->gf_remember_token = $value;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'gf_remember_token';
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->gf_email;
    }
}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ asset('/users') }}">
@csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="input-email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="input-password" id="input-password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

**config/auth.php**:

```
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\NewUser::class
        ],

        //'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

**After this changes I did the command** `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan event:clear`.

Answer (score 1):

config/auth.php:

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'gfuser' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'gfuser',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'gfuser' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\GFUsers::class
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

LoginController

```
Auth::guard('gfuser')->login($user); //array data with username and password
OR
if (Auth::guard('gfuser')->attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]) {//Redirect to dashboard}
```

Comment: Ok, the first part it's clear. For LoginController, do I put that code in a function? For example `public function login(){ Auth::guard('gfuser')->login($user); }`

Comment: Yes. You can create a function with request to get username and password. There's many ways to do it 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Answer (score 0):

You better not to make different tables for users, admin and technicians. They all suposed to be users. In one table and just with different attrinutes (for example - role, statuss, is_admin, is_user... ).

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how to do a custom login in laravel.

Comment: Actually I didn't get why you need it custom. Does default login and register functionality works or not? You can relative easy to overwrite default login controller methods. If default login works than in route file you have something like this - Auth::routes();. Instead of that line you can find where(vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php) is defined these auth routes and write them in route file classically. This would allow to change URI from /login to /public/users.