# Laravel 5.7 return id null after save()

Tags: php, laravel

When I have started with the project using *Laravel 5.7* and *PHP 7.3*, **`$info->id`** returned correctly the last insert id. Now, I did some changes at the login file ([all changes are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443021/custom-login-and-registration-with-auth-laravel-5-7)) and not at this files, but it doesn't work.
The **gf_id** in the table is **autoincrement**, the function **$info->id return null**. 
I have tried to delete the row "`public $incrementing = false;`" and to set it to false but there aren't any changes. I have tried with other function like `$info->_id` or `$this->id` and also have changed `$info->save` with `$info->create` but nothing, always null.
If I use **getPrimaryKey** return the error "**Call to undefined method**".
In the database the row is created correctly.
If I print the object $info with `dd($info);`, the result is this:

```
GfTableModel {#233 
  #table: "gf_table"
  #primaryKey: "gf_id"
  +timestamps: false
  +incrementing: false
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "gf_user" => 5
    "gf_new" => 1
    "gf_data" => "2019-03-22 14:08:28"
    "gf_object" => ""
    "gf_text" => ""
  ]
  #original: array:5 [
    "gf_user" => 5
    "gf_new" => 1
    "gf_data" => "2019-03-22 14:08:28"
    "gf_object" => ""
    "gf_text" => ""
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

This is my **GfTableModel.php**:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class GfTableModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'gf_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'gf_id';

    public $timestamps = false;  
    public $incrementing = true;

    public function insertNewRow(){

        $info = new GfTableModel();
        $info->gf_user = auth()->id();
        $info->gf_data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $info->gf_new = 1;
        $info->gf_object = "";
        $info->gf_text = "";
        $info->save();

        return $info->id;

    } 
}
```

Where am I doing wrong? Could it be a problem given by the command `php artisan config: cache`?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe try `return $info->gf_id`

Comment: Like I have wrote, I have tried already to set it true "I have tried to delete the row 'public $incrementing = false;' and to set it to true but there aren't any changes".

Comment: @ryantxr yes! I don't know why, but it works. I have tried this too before and it doesn't worked but now yes, so perfect, maybe I have wrote something wrong. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into something similar. As of Laravel 5.7, 5.8 you can do this:

```
return $info->getKey();
```

This works regardless of the name of the primary key.

Comment: How comes and the $info->id will not work? I had the same issue on my project; for some reason it stopped working and i had to go $info->getKey();

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$info = new GfTableModel();
```

With:

```
$info = GfTableModel::create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem.
Solution is :

```
return $info->getKey();
```

This method is useful when you don't know the name of primary key field.
This method get the value of the model's primary key.
It will returns a integer primary key value which is inserted using `$info->save();` method.

Comment: But I clerify right the answer with short discussion.